# CSS navigation bar hover issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list, hover

I am working on a website which has a centered horizontal navigation bar. This bar has to have round corners on the end parts along with a hover effect. All of this is sort of working, but the issue is that the hover of the nav bar is overflowing the actual size of the bar. Along with that there is a slight white space between every element. As you can see in the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25u473e1/2/) it doesn't look quite right. Another important note, is the fact that the navigation bar has to work with Bootstrap and the responsive functions. Which means nothing can be positioned absolute or float etc. Underneath I have also attached the html and css code.

### HTML

```
<div class="navTopRight">
 <ul class="naviTop">
 <li class="first"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#scrollToBot">Item1</a></li>
 <li><a href="Item2.html">Item2</a></li>
 <li><a href="Item3.html">Item3</a></li>
 <li class="last"><a href="Item4.html">Item4</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

### CSS

```
.navTopRight{
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.naviTop li {
   border:1px solid black;
   display: inline;
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color:#003340;
}

.navTopRight li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.navTopRight li a{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
} 

ul.naviTop li a:hover {
    background-color:#0099bf;
}

li.first{
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}
li.last{
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i think you basicly had everything right here there is just some small details.. if I understood your question correctly you wanted to just fill your li background without the blue color overflowing everything.. This is easiest done by changing the `padding:14px 16px;` to `padding:0px 16px;`

after that you wanted the empty white space removed and that can be achieved pretty simple by changing your html codes structure like  this:

```
                <li class="first"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li
                ><li><a href="#scrollToBot">Item1</a></li
                ><li><a href="Item2.html">Item2</a></li
                ><li><a href="Item3.html">Item3</a></li
                ><li class="last"><a href="Item4.html">Item4</a></li>
```

Notice how all the li tags ends just before the new one starts. Here is a working fiddle aswell! So no use of position or float needed!

https://jsfiddle.net/nfztdxr2/3/

Comment: You are a hero! Thank you very much.

Comment: i edited the answer change back to the a tag and change the padding instead, then it should work perfectly =)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix overflow hover just change this part of your css

```
ul.naviTop li {
   border:1px solid black;
   display: inline; -> *display: inline-block;*
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color:#003340;
}
```

here is the result https://jsfiddle.net/nfztdxr2/

Let me know if that is what you try to achieve, or maybe there is another concern?

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, it did make the hover issue go away. Although there is still a small gap between every word or element "so to speak". Do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: - you can add margin-right: -4px; to this class ul.naviTop li .
this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v3oq5jr5/  --and there are any other way to fix it, please read here https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

You can also set hover without "a"

ul.naviTop li:hover. {...}

It also looks better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have `padding: 14px 16px;` on `.navTopRight li a`, which is set to `display: inline;`. You can't give vertical margin/padding/etc to an inline element and have it affect the elements before/after it. So when you hover over those links, and the background color is applied, it looks really weird because the vertical padding becomes visible. Assuming that the navigation menu looks like you want it when the links aren't hovered, just remove that vertical (top/bottom `14px`) padding from the links.

```css
.navTopRight{
 text-align:center;
 list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.naviTop li {
   border:1px solid black;
   display: inline;
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color:#003340;
}

.navTopRight li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.navTopRight li a{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
} 

ul.naviTop li a:hover {
 background-color:#0099bf;
}

li.first{
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}
li.last{
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navTopRight">
                    <ul class="naviTop">
                    <li class="first"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#scrollToBot">Item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Item2.html">Item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Item3.html">Item3</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="Item4.html">Item4</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
```